# Best upgrade option for socket LGA771 Intel platform?

Tags: untagged

I've got a dual CPU Intel Dual-Core Xeon E5140 system. What's my best option to max the system performance-wise by CPU upgrading. It's an IBM server with LGA771 sockets. It's meant for typical LAMP usage.

Comment: What's the TPC limit of your server? or what exact model is it? we need to know this before we can recommend a CPU because you don't want the server to get too hot and go pop.

Comment: IBM System x3650 7979-51G, and I am limited to ~80-100W power consumption when idling in BIOS. So a gain on the green-it side of things would be nice as well. But I've heard more recent Xeons idle quite nicely around 40W...

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The X5492 was the most capable socket 771 chip with quad cores at 3.4Ghz but it is a 150W TDP chip so not everything can take it, you'd also want to ensure it was supported by your BIOS too. Other than that the X5472 was the best 120W 771 chip and the E5472 was the best 80W 771 chip. Hope this helps.

Comment: It does help, thanks. So nothing's there with a little more oomph in the 65W TDP arena, right? Going from 65W TDP to 80W TDP, would it add Watts when idling? (Is the newer CPU more conservative idling than the little more dated one?)

Comment: Newer CPU families require a different chipset/socket so that question is mostly irrelevant but generally yes.

Comment: The L5430 is a low-power (50W) quad core at 2.67Ghz - that's an option too of course. As for watts at idle, well you never design for that, you design for the maximum - unless you like fires or calling out engineers to fix things often anyway :)

Answer (score -1):

I have been doing some looking around and it seems the X5460 would be better than the X5472, it has a faster clock speed although the FSB is lower.

Performance is better on the X5460

http://www.cpu-world.com/Compare/854/Intel_Xeon_X5460_vs_Intel_Xeon_X5472.html